# SQL collation not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, utf-8, collation

I am trying to insert some utf8 encoded data into a mysql database. The special characters are correctly displayed in the browser, but not in my database. After manually changing the collation to utf8_unicode_ci and confirming that "this operation will attempt to convert your data to the new collation", the data gets displayed correctly. However if I create the table using

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_name (
  date date NOT NULL,
  searchengine VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  location VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  keyword VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  position INT NOT NULL,
  competition VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  url VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL    
)
```

and insert the data after creating the table, the data is still not shown correctly, even though the colletion is utf8_unicode_ci. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to answer -- are you getting question marks?  Gibberish?  Truncated text?  What?  In any case, see this for fixing your problem:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 1):

A **collation** is a set of rules that defines how to compare and sort character strings. Each collation in MySQL belongs to a single character set. Every character set has at least one collation, and most have two or more collations. A collation orders characters based on weights.

**utf8mb4_unicode_ci** is based on the Unicode standard for sorting and comparison, which sorts accurately in a very wide range of languages.

Comment: Manually setting the collation to utf8mb4_unicode_ci in phpmyadmin after inserting the data works fine. The data gets converted correctly. However setting the collation to utf8mb4_unicode_ci when creating the table like in the code shown above and inserting the data thereafter doesn't work. The data doesn't get converted.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-conversion.html

Comment: I think you need to use utf8  instead of utf8mb4 . Please check the link in the above comment.

Comment: I already used utf8 in the initial query shown in the question details. The result is the same.

Comment: @erlDan - `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` is needed for Emoji and Chinese.  For practically everything else, `CHARACTER SET utf8` will suffice.